# UserControls and activate buttons

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I try to develop an application using UserControls. I have a TableLayoutPanel on my MainForm charging different UserControls dynamically. One of this UserControl contains a FlowLayoutPanel in which buttons are loaded dynamically. At the begining this FlowLayoutPanel (with 12 buttons) is Enabled = false. My problem is that  if I click a button on my MainForm, I want that the FlowLayoutPanel (with 12 buttons) from my UserControl becomes Enabled = true. The status of my FlowLayoutPanel (with 12 buttons) is Enabled = true but my FlowLayoutPanel and my buttons are not active. Status is ok but in fact I can't click on my buttons because they are not active. Will I forget something? Is that not possible?

Here is some of my code:

```
public void OpenCaisseDialog()
{
   System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult OpenCashDialog = new DialogResult();
   OpenCaisseForm OCF = new OpenCaisseForm();
   OpenCashDialog = OCF.ShowDialog();
   if(OpenCashDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
      if ((Convert.ToInt32(OCF.tbMontantOuverture.Text)) > 0)
      {
         PanelTables.Controls.Clear();
         PanelTables.Enabled = true;
         PanelTables.Refresh();
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("La somme en caisse est égale à 0");
      }
   }
   PanelTables.Refresh();
}
```

thanks for your help. I tried your code, but I don't know if I use it well. I do this:

```
 public void OpenCaisseDialog()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult OpenCashDialog = new DialogResult();
        OpenCaisseForm OCF = new OpenCaisseForm();
        OpenCashDialog = OCF.ShowDialog();

        if(OpenCashDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(OCF.tbMontantOuverture.Text)) > 0)
            {
                PanelTables.Enabled += MyFlowLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged();
                PanelTables.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sum isn't equals 0");
            }
        }
        PanelTables.Refresh();
    }


    private void MyFlowLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged()
    {
        foreach(Control c in this.PanelTables.Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = this.PanelTables.Enabled;
        }
    }
```

I have an error with that line : PanelTables.Enabled += MyFlowLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged();

"+= can't be used with bool and void type"

Is it good that I used your code?

What type do I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from your code.
Try to do it manually

```
MyFlowLayoutPanel.Enabled += MyFlowLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged();

private void MyFlowLayoutPanel_EnabledChanged()
{
    foreach(Control c in MyFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = MyFlowLayoutPanel.Enabled;
    }
}
```